# Learning graphics from the very first pixel

Tags: 3d

I have been doing research on where to get started in computer graphics. I want to take an approach that starts me at a point where I can draw a single pixel in a window. I have found a few links and purchased the following books: *Game Engine Architecture* and *Fundamentals of Computer Graphics*. They teach the concepts of the graphics pipeline from a more abstract point of view and have been greatly helpful so far.

I want to start applying knowledge starting with the first pixel. Here are a few things to note:

- I know that better graphics engines and libraries already exist.
- I am not trying to create a better engine.
- I want to do this purely for education and to feed my hobby time.
- I would preferably like to use C/C++ when developing this hobby project.
- I am familiar with the math involved for 3D manipulations.
- I know this is not an easy thing to do.
- I understand it will take time.

I don't necessarily need to talk directly to the GPU. Speed is not a requirement for this project. If I get really into it and want to learn more about performance, I am sure I will have enough knowledge down the road to make that transition.

**Here is my question**: What is a good resource (book, article, etc.) that will help me get that first pixel on the window (again, preferably using C/C++)?

From there, I can start to apply more advanced concepts.